# Shutdown privileges problem

Tags: 14.10, sudo, shutdown, privileges

I have found that when I click the shutdown button when logged into a normal user account that once it has terminated all running processes and it says something about a modem shutting down, it can take up to 10-15 minutes or more to `halt`.

But when in the console running the command:

```
sudo poweroff
```

That it then does shutdown almost instantaneously. This then seems to be because as a normal user, I do not have the privileges to terminate a process which is then stopping the machine from shutting down.

This was not always the case, so is there any way around this?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work for me.

Instead of

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

I used

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

and it works. :-)

Comment: I changed the formatting. I hope this is ok for you.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to try:

1. Add a line to the following file: `/etc/default/grub`
   when you open the line will most likely read:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   change this line to be:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
   ```

   when you're all done you need to update `grub` for the change to take effect

   ```
   sudo grub-update
   ```

   I believe the first shutdown after these changes will have the same issues, but moving forward should be resolved.
2. Blacklist DMA this will default to use PIO instead.  Differences found [here](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-dma-and-pio/):

   details - do the above by going to

   ```
   /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```

   with your text editor and appending these line of text:

   ```
   blacklist dw_dmac
   blacklist dw_dmac_core
   ```